# Filter JSON column from MySQL table in spring boot

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, jpa

Below is my query to filter the json column in MySQL table ,

[image]

```
    public interface MpaCustomizationRepository extends
        JpaRepository<MpaCustomization, Serializable> {

@Query(nativeQuery = true, value = "select * from MPA_CUSTOMIZATION where json_contains(domain_based_properties, '{\"id\" : ?1}')")
MpaCustomization findByDomainBaseId(String domainId);

}
```

above method throws below SQL error,

[image]

but if I hard code the variable and run the query like below its works fine,

```
@Query(nativeQuery = true, value = "select * from MPA_CUSTOMIZATION where json_contains(domain_based_properties, '{\"id\" : 2}')")
    MpaCustomization findByDomainBaseId(String domainId);
```

How to fix this issue?

Comment: `.. WHERE domain_based_properties->>"$.id" = ?1 ..`

Comment: *above method throws below SQL error* Pay attention - MySQL claims that errorneous value is argument 1 which is `domain_based_properties` column's value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `$.id` for values when using native query, as SQL accepts like it only.
Other way, you may use `:id` and bind parameter `{\"id\":\"" + <value> + "\"}` to the query.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the following will work.

```
@Query(nativeQuery = true, value = "select * from MPA_CUSTOMIZATION where json_contains(domain_based_properties, ?1 , '$.id'")
MpaCustomization findByDomainBaseId(String domainId);
```

[Source](https://database.guide/json_contains-examples-in-mysql/)